# Trouble with this Prolog Rule

Tags: math, prolog, rules

If i have facts such as these:

```
ss(30,  1).
ss(29,  2).
ss(27,  3).
ss(23,  5).
ss(18,  7).
ss(13,  8).
ss( 8,  9).
ss( 4, 11).
ss( 3, 12).
```

How can i define a rule:

```
calculate_ss(Year, Score)
```

that gives:

`calculate_ss(10, S).` gives S = 9
`calculate_ss( 8, S).` gives S = 9
`calculate_ss(24, S).` gives S = 5

The answer should be the **highest Score** with the *Year* (from rule input) greater that the *year* (from the fact).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean "greater than or equal", and "highest score" is what is already provided in the numerical "ss" facts:

```
calculate_ss(Year, Score) :-
    calculate_ss_(Year, Score).
    
calculate_ss_(Year, Score) :-
    ss(Year, Score),
    % Found answer
    !.

calculate_ss_(Year, Score) :-
    % Look backwards through the years
    succ(Year0, Year),
    calculate_ss_(Year0, Score).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- calculate_ss(10, S).
S = 9.

?- calculate_ss(8, S).
S = 9.

?- calculate_ss(24, S).
S = 5.
```

Comment: Thank you. That's just what I needed.